# How to fire cross DB queries in HSQL DB?

Tags: mysql, database, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb

My application requires to capture information to generate daily/weekly reports, which requires me to fire queries from different databases crested in Mysql.E.g.
mysql> create database A;
mysql> create database B;

Create table 'sample1' in A and 'sample2' in B.
So most of the queries are in following pattern:
select * from A.sample1,B.sample2;

I wanted to unit test data access layer(DAL) using in-memory HSQL DB. I could not understand that how to create different databases in HSQL as in Mysql? I am using Spring ORM (JdbcTemplate) to interact with DB.

Is it right DB to unit test DAL?, If so how to create multiple DB in HSQL?
or Is there any other DB with which I can achieve this objective?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create multiple schemas in a single database in HSQLDB. Use CREATE SCHEMA Instead of CREATE DATABASE. You can then execute the same queries as in MySQL.

```
 CREATE SCHEMA A;
 SET SCHEMA A;
 CREATE TABLE SAMPLE1 ...

 CREATE SCHEMA B;
 SET SCHEMA B;
 CREATE TABLE SAMPLEB ...
```